# Vue.js change a leave transition dynamically after enter has been played

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a dynamic transition that tells my element to move left or right (it's a slider element). Since by default Vue only allows me to execute one transition, I'm using a dynamic transition property:

```
<transition v-bind:name="'slider-' + slideDirection">
```

Now, this slider has an enter and a leave transition, which adjusts according to the direction it's appearing or leaving to. All seem well, but..

When the element fills the condition for appearing, enter and enter-to transitions are executed properly, always. But leave and leave-to transitions do not get the updated direction if it's changed after the element appeared.

Here is a fiddle showing what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/nxLmdk9q/4/

In this example everything works, except as soon as you change directions, the element gets the previous direction animation for leave-to.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your slide transition starts before slideDirection is updated.
Try using nextTick function so that slide transition wait for direction to get updated.

Updated Example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    slideDirection: "right",
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    moveRight: function() {
      this.slideDirection = "right";
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.counter++;
      })

    },
    moveLeft: function() {
      this.slideDirection = "left";
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.counter--;
      })
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

div#slider {
  position: relative;
}

div#slider div:nth-child(even) {
  background: green;
}

div#slider div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

div {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

div:odd {
  background: blue;
}

.slider-right-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(100%);
}

.slider-right-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.slider-right-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.slider-left-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
}

.slider-left-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.slider-left-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translatex(100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <div id="slider">
    <transition v-bind:name="'slider-' + slideDirection">
      <div v-if='counter == 0'>
        0
      </div>
    </transition>

    <transition v-bind:name="'slider-' + slideDirection">
      <div v-if='counter == 1'>
        1
      </div>
    </transition>

    <transition v-bind:name="'slider-' + slideDirection">
      <div v-if='counter == 2'>
        2
      </div>
    </transition>

    <transition v-bind:name="'slider-' + slideDirection">
      <div v-if='counter == 3'>
        3
      </div>
    </transition>

  </div>

  <div>

    <button @click="moveLeft">
          &#x3C;&#x3C;
        </button>
    <button @click="moveRight"> 
          &#x3E;&#x3E;
        </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great - thank you!